# How to compare money type data in azure search service?

Tags: azure, odata, azure-cognitive-search

I have a azure search service with some money type data named 'price',and I met a problem when I try to sort or filter.

The test query expression is "&seach=*&$orderby=price desc",and the return result please refer the picture
[As you can see,the money type automatic convert to string type thus the sort result is compare the string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8qpu.png)

I am afraid that change the money type to double type will make some calculation mistake.Has anyone know how to fix this without change the data type?

Comment: 3 years and 3 months later, this is still a very painful topic :/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data type of the `price` field in your index schema is `Edm.String` - that's why the values are sorted as strings. You need to store the price as a number. Currently Azure Search doesn't have support for a money or decimal data type, so you need to use one of the numerical types like `Edm.Double`, `Edm.Int32` or `Edm.Int64`.

You can add a suggestion for money / decimal data type on [Azure Search UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am worry about once I change the data type to numerical types it will cause some calculation mistake?

Comment: You are not performing arithmetic calculations in Azure Search, so not sure what you mean by "calculation mistake".

Comment: Oh.I am sorry for the unclear expression. I just afraid use the float point number might cause some mistake.

Comment: A workaround is to use Edm.Int64 and ignore decimals. For example, for dollars you could represent $1.31 as 131